# How to use nft on linux bridge to block access to certain ip addr?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bridge, nftables

I have an Ubuntu box with a bridge `br0` defined. The bridge has `eth0` connected to the internet service and `eth1` connected to the network port of a PC. The bridge is functioning as expected and passing all traffic between `eth0` and `eth1`.

I want to put in a rule that will block access to certain external IP addresses (e.g. 1.1.1.1) from the PC. I presume `nft` is the way to do this. How do I write a rule so that nothing can pass `br0` going to/from 1.1.1.1.

The purpose here is to be able to simulate certain failures for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done using *nftables*' [bridge family](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Bridge_filtering).

> *nftables* provides the bridge family as a replacement for *ebtables*.

Create a table in the *bridge* family:

```shell
# nft add table bridge t
```

Create a chain to filter forwarded frames:

```shell
# nft add chain bridge t c '{ type filter hook forward priority 0; policy accept; }'
```

Create a rule to prevent IP packets from *eth1* to reach 1.1.1.1:

```shell
# nft add rule bridge t c iif eth1 ether type ip ip daddr 1.1.1.1 drop
```

That's it for a stateless firewall.

---

Since [Linux kernel 5.3](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_5.3#Networking) *nftables* also has support for direct stateful firewalling in the *bridge* path:

> Add native connection tracking support for the bridge. Before this
> patchset, only chance for people to do stateful filtering is to use
> the `br_netfilter` emulation layer, this is a step forward to deprecate
> it [...]

This allows to easily isolate the system in a single direction. For example to allow:

- incoming access to the PC with SSH
- outgoing access from the PC: the PC to use *ping* and DNS (`th` below stands for both *tcp* and *udp*)
- ARP (without which there is no IPv4 connectivity)
- all needed *reply traffic* (as first rule for performance reasons)
- and nothing else

one could use:

```shell
# nft add rule bridge t c ct state related,established accept
# nft add rule bridge t c oif eth1 ether type ip tcp dport 22 accept
# nft add rule bridge t c iif eth1 ether type ip meta l4proto {tcp, udp} th dport 53 accept
# nft add rule bridge t c iif eth1 ether type ip icmp type echo-request accept
# nft add rule bridge t c ether type arp accept
# nft add rule bridge t c drop
```

Some factorization is certainly possible and should be considered (eg: by using sets and [concatenations](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Concatenations)).

---

All examples above won't affect the Ubuntu box itself which can still reach and be reached by both sides. To affect traffic from the PC to the Ubuntu box (or resp. from the Ubuntu box to the PC), the same kind of rules can be done on a chain hooking in *input* (resp. *output*) instead of *forward*.

---

Note:

The [`br_netfilter`](https://ebtables.netfilter.org/documentation/bridge-nf.html) module should not be loaded (enabling by default the sysctl property `net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1`) to avoid unexpected interactions between native *bridge* rules and *ip* family rules which also affect *nftables* just as well as *iptables*. That means **running Docker or Kubernetes (the 2 usual users of `br_netfilter`) on the same system should be avoided** when doing network experiments (but is still possible with additional care, eg: by adapting [this UL SE Q/A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/657545/nftables-whitelisting-docker)).

Having `br_netfilter` loaded (and `net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1`) will mislead you into thinking the normal way of operations would be to filter in the *ip* family in the *filter*/*forward* hook. That's not the normal case, and *nftables* lacks additional features leveraging this such as *iptables*' [`physdev`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#physdev) match module: instead the goal has always been to do this natively in the *bridge* family and not rely on `br_netfilter`.

Comment: This works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your linux host is running as a router you need to configure ip_forwarding as well.

To answer your question, you could use nftables like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/nft 

flush ruleset

table inet my_table {
   chain INPUT {
      iifname br0 saddr 1.1.1.1 drop
      iifname br0 daddr 1.1.1.1 drop
   }

chain FORWARD {
      iifname br0 saddr 1.1.1.1 drop
      iifname br0 daddr 1.1.1.1 drop
   } 

}
```

and execute this with nft -f /path/to/your/nft.file

This is a bit useless though (I know you are learning nftables, do not take this too harsly). The best practice is to drop everything and allow only what is required, so not dropping specific traffic, but allowing specific traffic.

I've found the red hat 8 documentation very good for nftables, maybe you can learn from it as much as I did:

[rhel 8 nftables documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/getting-started-with-nftables_configuring-and-managing-networking#doc-wrapper)

Comment: You've misunderstood the question. The OP is taking about *L2* forwarding between bridge ports, not *L3* forwarding for traffics from/to a bridge.

Comment: It's not running as a router, but as a bridge. And this is not an attempt to implement security policy, it is an attempt to *simulate* certain network failures. It's a lab device, not a production device. Thanks for the answer and the link.

Comment: See the note about Docker/Kubernetes and `br_netfilter` at the end of my answer. Your answer suggests you might have the `br_netfilter` kernel module loaded.

Comment: aha, yes, I misread it indeed :-)